# How to implement a diverging color scale in d3 v4 using interpolate?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The interpolate function does not work in d3 v4. There are answers related to replacing interpolate with curve, but that works only for `d3.line` .

Hence need to implement a color scale to refer by my data points (circles, lines, text) which is diverging in nature.

Comment: I'm not clear on what isn't working - if updating a diverging color scale from v3 and you're running into problems regarding a diverging color ramp, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48172901/7106086) may be the issue you are running into. If this is not what you're looking for, adding additional information on what you are trying to do and what code you have would be beneficial in finding or writing a useful answer.

Comment: I am getting this error: "interpolate is not a function", though I am following the syntax according to https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/custom_color.html

Comment: Is it possible to share the lines defining the scale that are generating this error? There are a number of examples on the other page, they look fine to me.

Comment: `var myColor = d3.scaleSequential().domain([1,10])
  .interpolator(d3.interpolatePuRd);`

This line is causing error.

Comment: My initial suspicions were likely correct, it doesn't appear as though you are including d3-scale-chormatic, which in d3v4 is not part of the default bundle. The [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48172901/7106086) answer above should address this in greater detail.

Comment: I have actually included d3-scale-chromatic.

Comment: But this linked answer also helped me. Meanwhile, I used https://bl.ocks.org/EfratVil/903d82a7cde553fb6739fe55af6103e2

Comment: Glad you found something to work. The code you shared works for me - it generally helps if you can provide code to reproduce the error, or at least all the relevant code in the question.